# Install Rtools on R version 3.0.2

Tags: r, devtools, rtools

I've installed *devtools* for R, but when I call the library with:

```
library(devtools)
```

I get the following output:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but is not currently installed.
Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
```

So I executed the following code:

```
install.packages("Rtools", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/")
```

And I get the following output:

```
Installing package into ‘C:~/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning message:
package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)
```

I would appreciate any help that's out there to get Rtools onto my machine so I can call the devtools library.  Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rtools is not a package. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/