# Unable to install RTools even after updating to latest version of R

Tags: r, rtools

I am unable to install RTools on my computer even after updating to the latest version of R.

Here's the error I get.

[image]

Could I please get some help on this?

Comment: please see https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ . It is not  package

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023739/install-rtools-on-r-version-3-0-2